# c++ array initialization, good practice

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to be sure that this is not wrong: I initialize array with

```
 double* lower = input->getLowerBox();
```

where function getLowerBox() returns some double*. is it correct? Or shold I initialize this way::

```
double* lower = new double[nbP];
for (int i=0;i<nbP;i++)
     lower[i]=input->getLowerBox()[i];
```

or to avoid multiple calls to getLowerBox,

```
double* lower = new double[nbP];
double* tmp = input->getLowerBox();
for (int i=0;i<nbP;i++)
     lower[i]=tmp[i];
delete[] tmp;
```

Comment: Good practice would be using a vector instead of an array.

Comment: It depends on what `getLowerBox()` returns and the ownership of what it returns. Btw, You are assigning individual array elelments not initializing an array in last two cases.

Comment: A `std::vector` in a general case, or a `std::array` perhaps

Comment: in the last codeblock, you are deleting tmp and not lower, is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two steps recipe:

1. Change `Input::getLowerBox()` to return `std::vector<double> const&`
2. Use a copy if you want to modify the returned value, and the `const` reference instead

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you want to do. Do you need a new array or not.

Your first snippet doesn't create a new array, so memory management is more important.

For example:

```
double* lower = input->getLowerBox();
delete[] lower;
```

would possibly render `input->getLowerBox()` invalid. Or something like:

```
double* lower = NULL;
{
   Class input;
   lower = input->getLowerBox();
}
//...
```

would make `lower` a dangling pointer, if `input` clears the contents of the array in the destructor.

The last two snippets create new arrays. It is safer IMO, but also uses extra memory.

**Both are correct, depending on what you want to do. Whichever you choose, make sure to document it fully.**

Comment: The correctness depends on the ownership semantics of what `getLowerBox()`, depending on that the solutions *can* be incorrect.It is just wrong to say both are correct.

Comment: @Als so you're saying that if ownership of the array belongs to the class, the first variant is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The first way is fine.  You're going to return a pointer to a double, which I'm assuming is related to an array (If not, then please correct me).  By doing that, you're pointing to the first element of that array and then you can just index `lower` or use pointer arithmetic to access the other elements.

EDIT: Could you post the definition of `getLowerBox()` so it's more clear to what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to change `getLowerBox()` ? If so, I would change it so it returns a vector.

Depending on the implementation, it might return you a pointer which you can own or a pointer to an internal static (bad but possible) so you need to know what it's doing and act accordingly by retaining the pointer or taking a copy of the array respectively.

If you don't have control over `getLowerBox()` and you know the size of the array it returns, it would be a reasonable idea copy it to a vector

```
double* lower = input->getLowerBox(); 
vector<double> lowerV(lower, lower + N );
```

(where `N` is the size of the array - BTW this is just from memory, I haven't compiled it.)

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with the first one for multiple reasons.  It's cleaner, it avoids unnecessary calls / variable creation, etc.  Just make sure that input's a pointer if you're using "->"; otherwise use ".".